# WordPress 404 page returning with default in IIS7

Tags: theme-development, 404-error, iis

I've installed a number of WordPress sites across many different platforms and I'm finding that when installed on IIS7 I'm getting the nasty default IIS7 404 error. I nuked Window's hold on the 404 and now I'm receiving the standard.

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Is there an address I need to redirect to in order to display the WP404? Or does anyone have a better suggestion?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This resolved my 404 error. I essentially went into IIS and directed the 404s to a custom URL “/index.php?error=404“

[Article that explained how to resolve the error](http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2008/12/05/enable-custom-errors-in-wordpress-on-iis-7-0.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would redirect to your WP installation's 404 file. This should be in your theme's directory and be titled 404.php. If your installation does not have one by default then add one.

```
wordpress\wp-content\themes\your-theme
```

Comment: Tried that and it now is returning a different error "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred" I've tried a number of directory variations like %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot\wp-content\themes\"theme"\404.php still no dice.

Comment: Also tried Executing a URL on the site (relative to the site root) /wp-content/themes/"theme"/404.php that actually returns a blank page.

Comment: Don't specify a 404 in your web.config at all, this works on my WP installation.

Comment: the web.config path is directly related to IIS7 Error Pages. If I remove it than IIS throws an error Line number:34 Error: The path attribute is invalid

Comment: Weird. Looked at my installation. I just have the default. I never did anything to customize 404 errors. My IIS is set to  'Insert Content from Static File' and maps to %SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr\<LANGUAGE-TAG>\404.htm . But Wordpress seems to handle the 404'ing for me.

Comment: Also so this on blank page - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186659/why-does-my-wordpress-404-page-appear-blank